# How to make bubbles like those in the Google+ app?

Tags: java, android, google-plus

Does anyone know how to make a bubble with buttons like those in the Google+ Android app?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How was the username android not taken until 20 minutes ago?

Comment: @eternalmatt - Because the world hates us. It hates us hard.

Comment: Maybe they don't have to be unique? I don't know... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/).  Scroll down to the Gallery3D-like QuickActions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GreenDroid library.
More here:
http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=347

Answer (score 0):

That could just be a layout with the bubble set as background drawable. The bubble would then be a drawable resource in your project, probably a 9-patch.