# Android, how to create that small menu, as in the camera application?

Tags: android

I was wondering how can that little menu thing as in the picture below can be created?

Thanks! :)

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699005/android-how-to-make-bubbles-like-those-in-the-google-app/6699278#6699278

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are PopupWindows:

Some samples:
http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2010/04/popupwindow-in-android.html

http://www.mobilemancer.com/2011/01/08/popup-window-in-android/

[Is there a simple example of the PopupWindow class using Android v2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967863/is-there-a-simple-example-of-the-popupwindow-class-using-android-v2-0)